# VISÃO COMPUTACIONAL - RASTREAMENTO DE MULTIALVOS

Tags: c#, visão-computacional

Como realizar o rastreamento de pessoas em imagens e vídeo. Gostaria que me indicassem APIs ou bibliotecas eficientes que realizam essa tarefa.

[image: Imagem de Demostração]
Desejo um resultado semelhante ao desse [video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/InqV34BcheM).

Bem estou correndo o risco de receber pergunta negativa, mas acredito que essa pergunta ajudara também outras pessoas. Obrigado.

Comment: realmente é muito ampla... dá uma pesquisada no `OpenCV` vê se ajuda

Comment: tutorial: http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Tutorial